# (ViroReact) Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:36:9-38:41 to override

Tags: android, react-native, android-manifest

So I am trying to install a react-native library `@viro-community/react-viro` to the application. I have setup most of the things. I am getting error in the AndroidManifest.xml file in the project. While building I am getting the error:

> C:\Users\User\Desktop\ARView\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:38:13-38 Error:
> Attribute meta-data#com.google.ar.core.min_apk_version@value value=(211680000) from [:arcore_client] AndroidManifest.xml:38:13-38
> is also present at [com.google.ar:core:1.31.0] AndroidManifest.xml:38:13-38 value=(220920000).
> Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:36:9-38:41 to override.

I have added the attribute `tools:replace="android:value"` to the meta-data tag, but I am still getting the error. Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- added xmlns or xmlns:tools attribute -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- viro -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <!-- You may need these if doing any screen recording from within the app -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <!-- Other camera related features -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" tools:replace="required"/>
    <!-- Specifying OpenGL verison or requirements -->
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000" android:required="false" tools:node="remove" tools:replace="required" />
    <!-- Usage of accelerometer and gyroscope -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="false" tools:replace="required" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope" android:required="false" tools:replace="required" />
    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <!-- added below line for viro -->
      <meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.core" android:value="optional" tools:replace="android:value"/>
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**If I have skipped any details accidentally, please let me know.**

I have tried changing the attribute for the meta-data tag. It still gives me the error.